# How to connect wifi automaticaly all the time?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, network-manager

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on my Dell Inspiron 14. As my internet connection is slow when I try to download large file I can't be able to complete downloading at that time. And in the downloading time browsing speed get more slow that hampers my work flow.

So, I want to start the downloading when I go to sleep.
I also tried a downloading last night. I started the downloading, closed lid and then went to sleep. But, problem I have seen is in the morning I noticed that the wifi connection failed while I was sleeping. A wifi password taking field apear like this('ABCD' is not my wifi, its just a example, my wifi network name 'Raygraph')-

[image]

Provided that I checked the "connect automatically" box. My wifi general settings look like-

[image]

And my power settings looks like-

[image]

What can I do so that the wifi that I use will not be disconnected if the wifi is available and if disconnects when it is not available then it will be connected automatically when it is available again?

Note: if more information needed just comment.

Comment: Is there more than one 'Raygraph' available as you scan? A 5 Ghz channel of your router, perhaps?

Comment: @chili555 No. there is only one "Raygraph". I don't know router channel capacity.